# SharePoint Online : restricted view - documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, restricted-access

How can I modify permissions for documents?

When I have a folder with documents (A,B,C,D,E). I want that only user A and user B can see documents ABC, user C can see all of them and user D can see only documents AE.

The problem is that I can share only whole folder and I dont want to make three folders with almost same documents.

Comment: break permission inheritance for documents and grant unique permissions for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Create `one group` in SharePoint Permission and add everyone.

Now in SharePoint document library, create individual folder permission.

For document **'A'** folder add **UserA, UserB & UserC, UserD**

For document **'B'** folder add **UserA, UserB & UserC**

For document **'C'** folder add **User Group from permission group.**

For document **'D'** folder add **UserA & userE**

For document **'E'** folder add **UserD**

Comment: But thats the problem. I dont want to make 5 folders and have like 3 copies of a single document. I want one folder with 5 documents.
Dream would be something like ill share this folder to groupA and thel will see onle documents ABC but when i share the same folder to a groupB they will see document D

Comment: UserA in the sense one user or more than one person??

Comment: I wanted to point it out simply thats why I used only "user". Sometimes "userA" could be just one user but most likely it would be more than one.

Comment: May be, There is no directly link to exclude the user from SharePoint groups..

Comment: Its getting cofused. Lets say that i have a folder with 5 documents (ABCDE) and 3 groups. I want that group 1 would see documets AB, group 2 documents CD and group 3 all of them. Can i do it just with breaking permission inheritance or do i have to do something else?